# How can I return a number in prolog?

Tags: recursion, prolog, integer, return, predicate

I Have a very simple prolog program(I'm still learning) where I have a knowledge base that specifies you can take the bike to your destination or you can walk. The goal is to be able to know that if you can go from a to b with the bike, and from b to c by walking, we can then ask prolog if there is a route from a to c, so by first taking the bike to b, and then walking from b to c. I did this with the following code:

```
bike(a,b,30).
bike(b,c,20).
bike(c,d,25).

route_by_bike(From,To) :- bike(From,To,_).
route_by_bike(From,To) :- bike(From,Z,_), route_by_bike(Z,To).



walk(a,b,10).
walk(b,c,15).
walk(c,d,22).
walk(b,e,35).

route(From,To) :- walk(From,To,_) ; bike(From,To,_).
route(From,To) :- route(From,X), route(X,To)
```

I would now like to make a new predicate, namely extend the predicate route/2 to route/3 such that with the predicate route(From,To,Minutes) it can be derived if there is a route from From to To, by bike or by foot, and returns the amount of minutes that the route will take. The problem is that I have no idea how to make prolog actually return something, since I only made queries that will return False or true up until now. I have never made a program that actually returns a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to other languages, you do not *return things* in Prolog, you just establish relationships between terms. Your predicate `route/3` means: *it takes N minutes to go from point A to point B*.

All arguments might be viewed as inputs or outputs, depending on what you are interested in:

- if `route(bag_end, rivendell, M)` succeeds, `M` shall be unified with the number of minutes required to travel between `bag_end` and `rivendell`.
- if `route(X, london, 55)` succeeds, then `X` is a city that is exactly 55 minutes away from `london`.
- likewise, `route(A,B,C), C < 10` will try to unify `A`, `B` and `C` will all values that satisfy *both* goals (`route` and `>`), namely couples of places that are less than 10 minutes away, and the actual time needed to join them.

So you need to establish relationships between your arguments, and then you will be able to make queries that specifically unifies an unbound `Minutes` variables, and that will be the "result" associated with the query.